# как правильно использовать @PersistenceContext?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, h2

```
public class Start {

private static final String PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME = "MeineJpaPU";

public static EntityManager em = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME).createEntityManager();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    getAllFlowers();
}

public static void getAllFlowers() {


    TypedQuery<Flower> q = em.createNamedQuery("findCustomersByName", Flower.class);
    q.setParameter("n", "dmitriy");
    List<Flower> resultList = q.getResultList();

    for (Flower flowers : resultList) {
        System.out.println(flowers.toString());
    }

}
```

}

Этот код получает данные из базы

если же я использую

@PersistenceContext
   EntityManager em;

ничего не работает

если нужны еще какие то части кода, бин или конфигурации скажите добавлю

```
context.xml
.....
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"     class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" depends-on="flyway">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.accenture.model"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="database" value="H2" />
            <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaDialect">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect" />
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

.....

это persistance.xml
через который работает первый вариант

http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">

```
<persistence-unit name="MeineJpaPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

      <class>com.accenture.model.Account</class>
      <class>com.accenture.model.Flower</class>
  <properties>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa"/>
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>

  </properties>
```

Comment: @PersistenceContext аннотация для внедрения персистентности в приложение java ee, в частности в бины ejb (enterprise java bean). Там работает прекрасно. Можно ли использовать в приложении se не знаю. Специально не интересовался, но скорее всего нельзя

Comment: Покажите конфигурационные файлы.

Comment: Какие ещё конфигурационные файлы? Видно же, что в программе ничего кроме метода main нет. Для работы @PersistenceContext надо как минимум запустить какой-то контейнер, managed bean, если такие в принципе существует для самостоятельного приложения. `@PersistenceContext  Expresses a dependency on a container-managed EntityManager and its associated persistence context.`

Comment: Есть сушьность через первый вариант все работает из базы достает данные, не могу разобраться именно как все настроить чтобы работало через @PersistenceContext

Comment: Пример с @PersistenceContext  в студию!

Comment: ибо в методичке написано создать бин, бин создал сейчас добавлю

Comment: Что Вы называете бином, покажите пальцем

Comment: @Sergey конфигурацию контекста Spring и конфигурацию Hibernate.

Comment: Где в программе запуск контекста? Как в руководстве springa должен выглядеть метод main, чтобы этот spring начал работать?

Comment: у меня нет этго в методичке, я уже много чего перепробывал, в какую сторону копать то?

Comment: Лично я могу посоветовать курить мануалы `spring`-а, потому что сам с ним не работаю. Просто знакомился когда-то и это верно для любых контейнеров.

Comment: да майн то тут причем это просто для проверки работает или нет создано

Comment: Если он не при чём, зачем его показывать. Показывайте то, что не работает. Бин с `@PersistenceContext` и бин или что там у Вас, который пытается использовать бин с `@PersistenceContext`

Comment: действительно проблемма была не в коде а в голове) надо было больше про спринг почитать